# Can I automatically launch my application without user tapping local Notification in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, background-process, uilocalnotification

I want to be able to launch the app when a timer, which the user sets, goes to zero.  Will this keep my app from being accepted in the the app store?

Example:  The user sets a timer and exits the app/turns off the app.  When that timer hits zero the app launches and performs a function.

Comment: You have no control, without user interaction, to launch any application including your own while your app is in the background unless you are writing a jailbroken app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Launch Closed iOS App From Local Notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13447923/launch-closed-ios-app-from-local-notification)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Officially, it is not possible

for jailbroken device,
follow 
http://n8henrie.com/2012/07/scheduling-ios-apps/
there is some talk about it